# What's the fastest way to add a value to an array in PHP

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I'm working on a project that has an Arr helper class and I am curious about something: Is there a benefit in doing this:

```
/**
 * Sets an array value
 *
 * @param array  $array
 * @param string $path
 * @param mixed  $value
 *
 * @return void
 */
public static function set(array &$array, $path, $value)
{
    $segments = explode('.', $path);
    while (count($segments) > 1) {
        $segment = array_shift($segments);
        if ( ! isset( $array[$segment] ) || ! is_array($array[$segment])) {
            $array[$segment] = [];
        }
        $array =& $array[$segment];
    }
    $array[array_shift($segments)] = $value;
}

Arr::set($data['stories'], 'fields.age', '3');
```

Over this:

```
$data['stories']['fields']['age'] = '3';
```

Or is there a better, faster way?

Comment: That function has a slightly broader purpose (and is severely underdocumented of course). Therefore a comparison for "faster" doesn't make much sense.

Comment: The way in the function is used for any arbitrary "path" / depth/name of keys.  If you know the path to type the code then the second one is better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function is just easier to type - you do not have to make so many brackets and quotation mark. It makes things easier.

For performance: If you set the array values with normal syntax, it is faster, because you do not have to explode the path or check for existence before. But this takes not so many time.